# Sharing on Facebook and Twitter via ios 8 activity view controller

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, ios8, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have code in a share button that does this:

```
NSString *aText = _textToOutput;
UIImage *aPhoto = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData: _photoData];
NSURL *website = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"];



NSArray *objectsToShare = @[aText, aPhoto, website];

/* NSArray *includeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeMessage,
                               UIActivityTypeMail,
                               UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,
                               UIActivityTypePostToTwitter,
                               UIActivityTypePostToFlickr]; */    

UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                               UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
                               UIActivityTypePrint,
                               UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                               UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                               UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                               UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                               UIActivityTypePostToVimeo];

activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

But I am able to us sms and email and all 3 objects to share appear.  But on twitter, the URL doesn't appear in the popup and on Facebook the URL and NSString are missing from the popup. Did something change with ios or these apps? Thanks.

Comment: i think this may be the issue. http://openradar.appspot.com/18940777

Answer (score 4):

I am sharing in my app using below code.
It may helpful to you.

Code is:

```
 UIImage *screenshotTaken = @"Image Url";

NSString *message = @"My Application Name";
NSString *shareBody =@"put Link Here";

// NSLog(@"%@",shareBody);
NSArray *postItems = @[message,shareBody,screenshotTaken];
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
                                        initWithActivityItems:postItems
                                        applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This shared post to default setting on iphone.It shared on facebook,twitter,Flickr and email.

Comment: on iOS 8.3 this code doesnt show Facebook at all... i got facebook and facebook setting setup

Comment: I have found the same problem.. I do have Facebook app installed and am logined, but Facebook share option does not appear. Why?